# Catalyst::Engine::HTTP:Prefork

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am learning Catalyst from the book `the definitive guide to catalyst`. I have finished the demo application -- lolcatalyst_lite。 When I use command `"CATALYST_ENGINE=HTTP:Prefork script/myapp_server.pl"`, something is wrong; and according to the book, I rewrite the file lite.pm, the wrong is still on.

I take back what I added in file lite.pm. Why the command `"script/myapp_server.pl"` is still wrong:

```
Catalyst::Engine::HTTP:Prefork' is not a module name
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 50.
```

Did I set some argument in operation system? How can I go back?

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst has seen some pretty major changes under the hood since the book was published in this specific area.

The older Catalyst Engine code [has been replaced](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPSGI) with PSGI/Plack:

> Catalyst used to contain an entire set of Catalyst::Engine::XXXX classes to handle various web servers and environments (e.g. CGI, FastCGI, mod_perl) etc.
>
> This has been changed in Catalyst 5.9 so that all of that work is done by Catalyst implementing the PSGI specification, using Plack's adaptors to implement that functionality.

Have a look at the documentation for [Catalyst::PSGI](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPSGI) which explains why, and what to do with your existing code. The lolcat tutorial is quite current (v5.8), so [you should be able to upgrade it](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aUpgrading) without difficulty.

Comment: The book you have is still the best resource, IMO. It's really only this specific area where there have been changes to the framework that impact how current the book is. Did you read the link about upgrading? That's what you need.